# Prove that if the row vectors of a $n\times n$ matrix spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the columns are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence

I was able to prove that if a $n \times n$ matrix has linearly independent columns, then the row vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I am unsure how to prove the other way. So far, my proof is:

*Let the row vectors of A be $\vec r_{1},...,\vec r_{n}$. Then, $ span(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{\vec r_{1},...,\vec r_{n}\}$ and there exists some scalars $c_{1},...,c_{n}$ such that $c_{1} \vec r_{1}+...+c_{n}\vec r_{n}=\mathbb{R}^n$*

I don't know if what I have done so far is correct.

Thanks in advanced for you help.

Comment: What is the span of a vector space?? Also your last equality is meaningless, since the l.h.s. is a vector and the r.h.s. is a vector space.

Comment: You can find this proof in any linear algebra book. The rank of a matrix is equal to the rank of its transpose or, in other words, the maximum number of linearly independent rows is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent columns. Your question is a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

if $R_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j} e_{i,j}$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n$ are $n$-linearly  independents row vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $C_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,j} e_{i,j}$ are $n$-linearly independents column vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i R_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  we have:
\begin{align}
x &=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i R_i\\
& = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j} e_{i,j}\\
& = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,j} e_{i,j}\right)\\
& = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_jC_j
\end{align}

We can change indexation of $\lambda_i$ to $\lambda_j$ and switch the sum signs because they are a finite sums.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this can be that if the rows span $\mathbb R^n$, then the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix is non-zero.

This means determinant of the transpose of the $n\times n$ matrix is also non-zero.

This means we have $n$ columns which are linearly independent.

This means the columns span $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Why would the determinant be $0$?

Comment: @Bernard it should have been non-zero. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: How would I connect linear independence to the columns spanning Rn?

Comment: @Sayan Dutta: Lapsus calami also happen to me from time to time  ; o)

Comment: @pupuynum $n$ linearly independent vectors will always span an $n$-dimensional space